# 3-D printing initial stage for a beginner

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I am a new-bee to 3-D printing. I want to learn about it as much as I can. So, where to start? like a total beginner. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: please see more here: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D printing SE! This is not an average forum site, but is specifically designed to solve specific questions. Before you ask a question, it is custom that you have familiarized yourself. Please try to Google "3D printing". E.g. https://3dprintingforbeginners.com/category/tips-techniques/, https://toms3d.org/ and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCb8Rde3uRL1ohROUVg46h1A are a good place to start. If you have specific questions after that, please feel free to ask them. Do note the fore mentioned https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @0scar Thanks for the info! I guess, I'll better start learning then!

Comment: +1 for good luck. If you are wanting to build your own printer then the [RepRapWiki](https://reprap.org/wiki/RepRap) is invaluable. A little hard to navigate maybe, but once you get a better idea about 3D printing as a whole, and start to design/build a printer, then you will definitely need some information from there at some point. Please come back here, to SE.3D Printing, when/if you have a specific issue that we can help you with. :-)

Comment: like anything else, youtube